# How can I get the data from the first column from my DataSet?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I am unable to get the data from my `DataSet`

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + dbPath;
string cmdstr = "select * from serverManagerTable";
DataSet data = new DataSet();

using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com))
         da.Fill(data);
}

LinkLabel l = new LinkLabel();
l.Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

The text coming out is "2" when it should be

I am trying to get the data from the 1st column in the table

---

The table has this data

```
SERVER1 | Explorer.exe
SERVER2 | svMan.exe
SERVER3 | chatApp.exe
SERVER4 | Explorer.exe
SERVER5 | cmd.exe
```

Comment: _"The text coming out is "2" when it should be "_ Should be _what_?

Comment: Can you please clarify the part that Tim mentioned? Also if you wanna get only one row with one column, using `ExecuteScalar` is a better way.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment there is a field value `2` somewhere in that `serverManagerTable`. In which column and which row is it (the name of the column is useful to know)?

Answer (score 4):

It's currently not clear what you expect instead of "2". However...

- you should list all columns explicitly in production code [instead of using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- you should use the strongly typed [`Field` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of converting everything to `string` with `ToString`
- you should use [`OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of loading a complete `DataTable` or even a `DataSet` if you just want a single value anyway

Maybe this helps also to fix your actual issue.

Comment: I was not expecting 2. The data in the table is "SERVER1" "SERVER2" "SERVER3"... "SERVER12"

Comment: If the value is `Server1` i don't see how it's possible that you get `"2"`. Inspect your `DataTable`, what does it contain in which order. Show it us.

Comment: I changed the SQL to include the field names and I am now getting the expected result. I think it was the SQL query generating something

Comment: @softwareisfun: you see that it's always good to list the column names explicitly. The link i've provided in my answer also mentiones other advantages.